# Missing database connection when trying to set up Adonis with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, adonis.js

After configuring my `.env` file to use Postgres, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeException: E_MISSING_DB_CONNECTION: Missing database connection {postgres}. Make sure you define it inside config/database.js 
file
```

Here is my `.env` file:

```
...
DB_CONNECTION=postgres
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=postgres
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, even though I found in some Adonis documentation that the database connection should be `postgres`, I set the following in the .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=pg
```

You also have to install the pg module if you don't have it

```
npm i --save pg
```

I think maybe the module changed names at some point?